# Отправка письма PHP

Tags: php, html, email, отправка

Имеется HTML разметка

```
<form method="post" id="fsave" action="">
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" required="required" maxlength="70" id="name" placeholder="Имя*"/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" required="required" maxlength="70" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон*"/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" required="required" maxlength="150" id="subject" placeholder="E-mail*"/>
                </label>
                <label><textarea name="message" class="msgforadmin" placeholder="Расскажите, что Вас интересует &#9998;"></textarea>
                </label>
                <p><button id='sender' class="button" type="submit">Отправить</button></p>
            </div>
        </form>
```

И PHP код

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $email = 'lulz@another.com';
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
    $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST["subject"]);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]);
    $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]);
    $json = array();

    if (!$phone or !name or !$subject or !$message) {
        $json['error'] = 'Вы зaпoлнили нe всe пoля';
        echo json_encode($json);
        die();
    }

    function mime_header_encode($str, $data_charset, $send_charset) { 
        if($data_charset != $send_charset)
        $str=iconv($data_charset,$send_charset.'//IGNORE',$str);
        return ('=?'.$send_charset.'?B?'.base64_encode($str).'?=');
    }

    class TEmail {
    public $from_email;
    public $from_name;
    public $to_email;
    public $to_name;
    public $subject;
    public $data_charset='UTF-8';
    public $send_charset='windows-1251';
    public $body='';
    public $type='text/plain';

    function send(){
        $dc=$this->data_charset;
        $sc=$this->send_charset;
        $enc_to=mime_header_encode($this->to_name,$dc,$sc).' <'.$this->to_email.'>';
        $enc_subject=mime_header_encode($this->subject,$dc,$sc);
        $enc_from=mime_header_encode($this->from_name,$dc,$sc).' <'.$this->from_email.'>';
        $enc_body=$dc==$sc?$this->body:iconv($dc,$sc.'//IGNORE',$this->body);
        $headers='';
        $headers.="Mime-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers.="Content-type: ".$this->type."; charset=".$sc."\r\n";
        $headers.="From: ".$enc_from."\r\n";
        return mail($enc_to,$enc_subject,$enc_body,$headers);
    }

    }

    $emailgo= new TEmail;
    $emailgo->from_name= $phone;
    $emailgo->to_email= $email;
    $emailgo->body= $name;
    $emailgo->from_email= 'support@another.ru';
    $emailgo->subject= $subject;
    $emailgo->body= $message;
    $emailgo->send();

    $json['error'] = 0;

    echo json_encode($json);} else { echo 'GET LOST!';}?>
```

Задача: значение из тега с `name="message"` и из тега с `name="subject"` должны оказаться в поле `body` нашего сообщения в порядке их ввода. Т.е. сперва e-mail, а ниже - остальной текст сообщения введенный через `name=message` В PHP не особо силен. Как мне решить эту задачу?

Comment: не зная основ уже на классах пишите ) читайте: https://habrahabr.ru/post/38754/ еще:http://www.php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?string2

Comment: Добрый день.
А проверку полей вы в нем не делаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если просто в сообщение в письмо добавить, то заменить

```
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]);
```

на

```
$message = $subject . htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Кажется это то, что нужно)

Comment: Пожалуйста!
Где-то должна быть кнопка "Правильный ответ."

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется в виду сообщение об ошибке, то заменить

```
if (!$phone or !name or !$subject or !$message) {
        $json['error'] = 'Вы зaпoлнили нe всe пoля';
        echo json_encode($json);
        die();
    }
```

на

```
$json['error'] = '';
if (!$phone) {
        $json['error'] .= ' Вы не заполнили телефон. ';
    }
if (!$name) {
        $json['name'] .= ' Вы не заполнили имя. ';
    }
if (!$subject ) {
        $json['subject'] .= ' Вы не заполнили тему. ';
    }
if (!$message ) {
        $json['message'] .= ' Вы не заполнили сообщение. ';
    }
if($json['error']){
echo json_encode($json);
        die();
}
```